# Adding/Subtracting in binary and hexadecimal number systems?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science

I have two numbers(in decimal):

```
M = 3892.74
N = 9341.65
```

I am trying to add and subtract them in binary numbers and then in hexadecimal numbers. I manage to convert the numbers into binary/ hexadecimal with 4 fraction digits.

```
M = 111100110100.1011   and M = f34.bd70
N = 10010001111101.1010 and N = 247d.a666
```

and I have found `M + N = 13234.51 = 11001110110010.0101 = 33b2.83d6`
  I am having trouble doing the M - N ? Is there negative numbers in alternate number systems and how would I carry out this subtraction ? If my earlier work can be verified, I would also appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are negative numbers. Have a look at the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) and the example therein.